# ec2instance automation with python script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a python script on ec2 instance . The python file is residing on s3.
I am able to run manually from ec2 instance using iam role which allow access to s3 folder and files.

The question is , how can i automate  the start and stop of ec2 instance whenever needed  and how  to invoke /pass  a python file to run  upon starting the ec2 instance and stop the instance once the python files completes the execution.

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: Might help: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community ‍‍](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Comment: @Sidh What would be the trigger that 'starts' the instance? Would it always run the same Python script, or would it need to copy it from S3 each time the instance starts?

Comment: it would be the same python script.  the requirement is to host a python file on  aws and run it as a scheduled job at a specific  time everyday.  As of now i am able to fetch the python file residing on s3 and was able to execute it on top of ec2 manually.

Comment: How long does the script take to run? Have you considered using AWS Lamba to run the script? (Note: It Lambda functions can only run for a maximum of 15 minutes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements seem to be:

- Schedule an Amazon EC2 instance to start at a specific time every day
- The instance should run a Python script after starting
- When the Python script has finished running, Stop the instance

**Start EC2 instance on a schedule**

You can use **Amazon EventBridge** to trigger an **AWS Lambda function** on a schedule.

You can code the Lambda function to call `StartInstances()` on the EC2 instance to Start it.

**Run a script on startup**

Install a script into the `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/` directory. This script can download the Python program from S3 and then run it.

When the EC2 instance starts up, it will automatically run any script in that directory.

**Stop the instance when the script is finished**

At the end of the script, add the command:

```
shutdown -h now
```

This will turn off the instance and place it in the **Stopped** state.

(This assume that the script is running as root. If it is running as another user, it will need to use `sudo shutdown -h now`.)

Answer (score 0):

EC2 instances use [cloudinit](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which you can customize to run a given script on each boot. You can use use regular os tools from python to shutdown your instance (e.g. `shutdown -h now`).

Answer (score 0):

Here another alternative could be to use lambda function instead of EC2 instance to run the python script if maximum execution time of script is less than 15 minutes. Go serverless with AWS lambda rather than EC2. just add your script code in AWS lambda and schedule lambda function from AWS event bridge to invoke it.